# ¿Cómo generar un XML desde JAVA?

Tags: java, xml

Cuento con las siguientes clases(Cada una con su constructor y métodos):
Clase datos generales:

```
public class DatosGenerales implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6335462093076037064L;
    public String identificadorTool;
    public String numReporte;
}
```

Clase piezas:

```
public class Piezas {

    String posicion;
    String numeroParte;
    String descripcion;
    String monto;
    String cambioPrecio;
...
}
```

Clase Pintura:

```
public class Pintura {

    String posicion;
    String descripcion;
    String ut;
    String monto;

    ...
}
```

Clase Operacion:

```
public class Operacion {

    String codigo;
    String descripcion;
    String ut;
    String monto;
...

}
```

Las cuales, tengo que desarrollar un XML con cada atributo de esas clases, es decir:

```
<DatosGenerales>
    <indentificadorTool>...</identificadorTool>
    <numReporte>...</numReporte>
</DatosGenerales>
<Piezas>
    <posicion>...</posicion>
    <numeroParte>...</numeroParte>
    ...
    <cambioPrecio>...</cambioPrecio>
</Piezas>
<Piezas>
    <posicion>...</posicion>
    <numeroParte>...</numeroParte>
    ...
    <cambioPrecio>...</cambioPrecio>
</Piezas>
<Piezas>
    <posicion>...</posicion>
    <numeroParte>...</numeroParte>
    ...
    <cambioPrecio>...</cambioPrecio>
</Piezas>
<Pintura>
    <posicion>...</posicion>
    <descripcion>...</descripcion>
    ...
    <monto>...</monto>
</Pintura>  
<Operacion>
    <codigo>...</codigo>
    <descripcion>...</descripcion>
    ...
    <monto>...</monto>
</Operacion>
```

Partiendo de esta clase:

```
public class ValuacionTool {



    private DatosGenerales datosGenerales;
    private Collection<Operacion> operacions;
    private Collection<Piezas> piezas;
    private Collection<Pintura> pinturas;

...
}
```

Qué métodos podría emplear?
Gracias.

Además aplico las librerias de java.xml

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class XMLTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          String nombre_archivo = "geekyxml";
            ArrayList key = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<ValuacionTool> value = new ArrayList<ValuacionTool>();

            DatosGenerales DG = new DatosGenerales();
            Piezas pieza = new Piezas();
            Pintura pintura = new Pintura();
            Operacion operacion = new Operacion();

            DG.setIdentificadorTool("x");
            DG.setNumReporte("95647825");

            pieza.setPosicion("1585"); 
            pieza.setNumeroParte("180827111949167");
            pieza.setDescripcion("TORNILLOS DE SUJECIO");
            pieza.setMonto(125.32);
            pieza.setCambioPrecio("0");

            pintura.setPosicion("58592");
            pintura.setDescripcion("TORNILLOS DE SUJECIO");
            pintura.setUt(9);
            pintura.setMonto(452.56);

            operacion.setCodigo("561292");
            operacion.setDescripcion("TORNILLOS DE SUJECIO");
            operacion.setUt(3);
            operacion.setMonto(1254);

            key.add("Datos Generales");

            key.add("Pieza");
            value.addAll((Collection<? extends ValuacionTool>) pieza);

            key.add("Pintura");
            value.addAll((Collection<? extends ValuacionTool>) pintura);

            key.add("ManoDeObra");
            value.addAll((Collection<? extends ValuacionTool>) operacion);

            try { 
                generate(nombre_archivo, key, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        public static void generate(String name, ArrayList<String> key,ArrayList<ValuacionTool> value) throws Exception{

            if(key.isEmpty() || value.isEmpty() || key.size()!=value.size()){
                System.out.println("ERROR empty ArrayList");
                return;
            }else{

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                DOMImplementation implementation = builder.getDOMImplementation();
                Document document = implementation.createDocument(null, name, null);
                document.setXmlVersion("1.0");

                //Main Node
                Element raiz = document.getDocumentElement();
                //Por cada key creamos un item que contendrá la key y el value

                for (ValuacionTool valuacionTool : value) {
                    //Item Node
                    Element itemNode = document.createElement("ITEM"); 

                    //Key Node
                    Element keyNode = document.createElement("KEY"); 
                    Text nodeKeyValue = document.createTextNode(key.get(0));
                    keyNode.appendChild(nodeKeyValue);      

                    //Value Node
                    Element valueNode = document.createElement("VALUE"); 
                    Text nodeValueValue = document.createTextNode(value.get(arg));           
                    valueNode.appendChild(nodeValueValue);

                    //append keyNode and valueNode to itemNode
                    itemNode.appendChild(keyNode);
                    itemNode.appendChild(valueNode);
                    //append itemNode to raiz
                    raiz.appendChild(itemNode); //pegamos el elemento a la raiz "Documento"
                }              
                //Generate XML
                Source source = new DOMSource(document);
                //Indicamos donde lo queremos almacenar
                Result result = new StreamResult(new java.io.File(name+".xml")); //nombre del archivo
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.transform(source, result);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hay muchos métodos y formas, por favor comparte lo que has intentado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar

Comment: Actualizo mi clase main donde agrego los valores. @RuslanLópez

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar utilizar las anotaciones `@XmlRootElement` y `@XmlElement` para mapear tus clases a un formato *XML*.

Por ejemplo:

```
@XmlRootElement
class ValuacionTool {

    private DatosGenerales datosGenerales;
    private Collection<Operacion> operacions;
    private Collection<Piezas> piezas;
    private Collection<Pintura> pinturas;

    ...

    @XmlElement
    public void setDatosGenerales(DatosGenerales datosGenerales) {
        this.datosGenerales = datosGenerales;
    }
    ...
}
```

Y realizar lo mismo con las demás clases "*hijas*", por ejemplo, con la clase `DatosGenerales` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
@XmlRootElement
class DatosGenerales implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6335462093076037064L;
    private String identificadorTool;
    private String numReporte;

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getIdentificadorTool() {
        return identificadorTool;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setIdentificadorTool(String identificadorTool) {
        this.identificadorTool = identificadorTool;
    }

    public String getNumReporte() {
        return numReporte;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setNumReporte(String numReporte) {
        this.numReporte = numReporte;
    }
}
```

Una vez que hayas insertado en todos los métodos que *setean* la anotación `@XmlElement` y tu clase `ValuacionTool` instanciada con lo que necesitas puedes realizar esto:

```
final ValuacionTool tool = new ValuacionTool();
...
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ValuacionTool.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tool, sw);

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final String s = sw.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Lo cual imprime la siguiente salida:

```
<valuacionTool>
    <datosGenerales>
        <identificadorTool>x</identificadorTool>
        <numReporte>95647825</numReporte>
    </datosGenerales>
    <operacions>
        <codigo>561292</codigo>
        <descripcion>TORNILLOS</descripcion>
        <monto>1536</monto>
        <ut>3</ut>
    </operacions>
    <piezas>
        <cambioPrecio>0</cambioPrecio>
        <descripcion>TORNILLOS DE SUJECIO</descripcion>
        <monto>125.32</monto>
        <numeroParte>180827111949167</numeroParte>
        <posicion>1538</posicion>
    </piezas>
    <pinturas>
        <descripcion>TORNILLOS DE SUJECIO</descripcion>
        <monto>125.32</monto>
        <posicion>1538</posicion>
        <ut>3</ut>
    </pinturas>
</valuacionTool>
```

En caso de querer guardar la salida en un archivo puedes optar por añadir las siguientes líneas dentro del bloque `try/catch`:

```
File file = new File("salida.xml");
...
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tool, file);
```

Y estas son las clases que importo para que funcione correctamente:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.StringWriter;
```

#### Referencias

- [@XmlRootElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)
- [@XmlElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html)
- [JAXB Hello World Example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Muchas gracias!, una duda... para que es la variable "tool" en: `jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tool, sw)`

Comment: Olvide incluirlo pero es `final ValuacionTool tool = new ValuacionTool();`

Comment: Y cuando ocupo guardar el archivo, para que es "customer" en `jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);`

Comment: Es la misma variable `tool` olvide cambiarlo a tu ejemplo. Gracias.

Comment: Por si alguien ocupa, JAXB desaparece en versiones más actuales de Java, lo más correcto es agregar JAXB como dependencia, más info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Seguí el ejemplo de las anotaciones `@XmlRootElement` y `@XmlElement` y me funciona, pero no me mantiene la letra mayúscula al principio de cada nodo, como puedo hacer para que el XML se me genere respetando la letra mayúscula en la primera posición de cada nodo.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la librería [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/), sirve para parsear de XML a objetos java y viceversa. Te recomiendo que leas el [Alias tutorial de Xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html) ya que con eso aprendes casi todo de como usarla.

Mini ejemplo de una biblioteca:

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
public class Libro {
    private String tipo;
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    public Libro(String tipo, String titulo, String autor) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

}
package ejemplo.xstream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Biblioteca {
    List<Libro> libros=new ArrayList<Libro>();
    public Biblioteca(Libro libro) {
        this.libros.add(libro);
    }
    public List<Libro> getLibros() {
        return libros;
    }
    public void add(Libro libro) {
        this.libros.add(libro);
    }
}
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverter;
public class StringConverter implements SingleValueConverter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class arg0) {
        return arg0.equals(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object fromString(String arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Object arg0) {
        return (String) arg0;
    }

}
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
public class XstreamTransformacion {
    private static XStream configuracion(){
        XStream xstream=new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("biblioteca", Biblioteca.class);
        xstream.alias("libro", Libro.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(Biblioteca.class, "libros");
        xstream.useAttributeFor(Libro.class, "tipo");
        xstream.registerConverter(new StringConverter());   
        return xstream;
    }
    public static String toXML(Biblioteca biblioteca){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"+xstream.toXML(biblioteca);
    }             
    public static Biblioteca fromXML(String xml){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return (Biblioteca)xstream.fromXML(xml);
    }
}
package ejemplo.xstream;
public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Biblioteca biblioteca=new Biblioteca(new Libro("Novela", "Don quijote", "Miguel de cervantes"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("teatro", "Romeo y julieta", "William Shakespeare"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("cuento", "El Aleph", "Jorge Luis Borges"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("poemas", "Antologia", "Mario Benedetti"));
        String xml=XstreamTransformacion.toXML(biblioteca);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }

}
```